# How can most apps play AAC for free?

Tags: audio, codec, licensing, aac

Web says that AAC is not a free format, and decoding software must pay the fee. I have downloaded a sample AAC file, and tried playing it with free apps. On Android, Google Files, VLC, and Musicolet could play it. On Ubuntu Linux, Audacious, MPV, FireFox could play it. On Windows. PotPlayer  can play it with in-built codec (see screenshot below), and VLC, Foobar 2000 could also play it.

How can they play it. Did the developers pay licensing fee? Or is there some sort of exemption for free software?

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

### Playback, encoding, streaming and distribution of AAC encoded audio is free.

#### It has to do with licensing and patent use. Compiled code that uses AAC *must* be licensed; but compiling from source code is free.

As explained [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding#Licensing_and_patents); bold emphasis is mine:

> “**No licenses or payments are required for a user to stream or distribute content in AAC format.** This reason alone might have made AAC a more attractive format to distribute content than its predecessor MP3, particularly for streaming content (such as Internet radio) depending on the use case.
>
> However, a patent license is required for all manufacturers or developers of AAC codecs. **For this reason, free and open source software implementations such as FFmpeg and FAAC may be distributed in source form only, in order to avoid patent infringement.**
>
> The AAC patent holders include Bell Labs, Dolby, Fraunhofer, LG Electronics, NEC, NTT Docomo, Panasonic, Sony Corporation, ETRI, JVC Kenwood, Philips, Microsoft, and NTT.”